# Android - How to retrieve data from Parse.com and show them into a listview?

Tags: android, database, listview, parse-platform

I would retrieve some data from Parse.com and show them into a listview (using Android), but I don't know how, can you show me an example of: how to do a simple query and how to insert data in a listview? I.e. my class is named "Profiles" and it contains two columns: "name" (string) and "age" (number).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, I don't know how to approach with this problem, on Parse.com there is no documentation about it and the others questions here on stackoverflow didn't help me...

Answer (score 1):

`Parse` provides all documentation for querying data from their storage. They are providing simple examples to understand it. [Please reffer this](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) It may help you.

Comment: I've already read the documentation, but there is nothing about showing data into a listview...

Comment: you can get all data by class object. Once you get the class object you can use for loop to get your required data from there. Then you can show it in your own listview. Here is a simple tutorial about `listview` http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html